# Photo OCR to file name

Tags: ocr

I have a large amount of image files with text in them, I would like to know if there is a way to run an OCR scan and mass change the file names based on the OCR scan details. Windows 10

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can find a batch OCR scan, but the resulting file-names will be based on the original names.

Comment: *Could it be done?* Yes. But more info would be needed. E.G., if the text is 6 kB long, what portion to use for file name? When OCR produces gibberish, as of ten occurs, what to do?